# Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string

Tags: php, string, strpos

When I use strpos() for single string then it works fine but when I grab html from URL and pass this html to this function then this error shows. I am not able to understand the reason behind this. Please anyone explain this warning ?

```
$html = file_get_content("site URL");
function getHtml ($html, $startTag, $endTag, $start) {
        $tagStart = strpos($html, $startTag) + $start;
        $tagEnd = strpos($html, $endTag, $tagStart);
        return substr($html, $tagStart, $tagEnd - $tagStart);
}
```

and error points to the $tagEnd line in this function .

Comment: Show an example. Your offset is probably greater than the length of the string you're searching.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation comments](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#93816):

> This function raises a warning if the offset is not between 0 and the length of string:
>
> `Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in ...`